# Can't connect to memcache

Tags: php, apache, caching, memcached

I am trying to connect to memcache as they suggest:

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->pconnect('localhost',11211);
```

But i get:

```
Notice: Memcache::pconnect() [memcache.pconnect]: Server localhost (tcp 11211) failed with: Connection refused (111) in /home/user/public_html/website.com/includes/basedatos.php on line 26
```

Any idea why?

Comment: is memcahced running on your computer on port 11211?

Comment: That generally means memcache isn't running. Have you set it up?

Comment: hm.. @Amber it seems i followed the wrong steps. my question is the second step i took from installing it via pecl, what do i need to do to set it up?

Comment: memcache is two parts: a client interface (the PHP version of which is installed via PECL or similar) and the actual memcache server daemon, which needs to be installed as a completely separate program or system package. What OS are you running on? If it's a debian-based flavor of Linux, try `sudo apt-get install memcached`

Comment: @Amber I see, so i am using CentOS, shall i try? and after that apt-get is there anything else i need to do? thanks a lot

Comment: On CentOS you'll probably need to do `yum install memcached`. After that, you may need to start the server (most likely with `/etc/inid.d/memcached start`. (`yum` might automatically start it up for you, though; I forget.)

Comment: [root@vps ~]# /etc/inid.d/memcached start
-bash: /etc/inid.d/memcached: No such file or directory                                                             [root@vps ~]# /etc/inid.d/memcache start
-bash: /etc/inid.d/memcache: No such file or directory                                      
[root@vps ~]#

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to actually install the `memcached` server so that it can be connected to. On CentOS, this can be done with...

```
sudo yum install memcached
```

(on debian flavors of linux, use `apt-get` instead of `yum`)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - the syntax Amber provides is correct, [read this](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/installing-memcached-redhat-or-centos). You may need to do some web-searching around the problem since we don't have access to try a few other things that would come to mind if we were at your console. Do some digging `:)`.

Comment: (Also the fact that some distros have sane package repositories that actually include most of the things you might want in a basic server. *cough*)

Comment: I was able to do it like this http://kb.liquidweb.com/install-memcached-on-centos-5/ but now i have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776545/memcache-call-to-a-member-function-get-on-a-non-object :(

Comment: i think this is incorrect isnt that so, because he is asking about Memcache and the given answer is for the "Memcached" two different things

Comment: @user1179459 memcached is the memcache server.

Comment: so there are two php extensions called `memcache` and `memcached`, both of which are only client apis to a third and totally separate server program called `memcached`...  this seems stupid...

Comment: Found a great tutorial on doing this on a mac. Includes some Drupal stuff too but I was mostly interested in the brew direction. http://mark.shropshires.net/blog/setting-memcached-mac-local-drupal-development

Comment: Thanks +1 simple solution

Answer (score 18):

This may be obvious, but make sure that memcached is actually running:

```
service memcached start
```

Comment: For me, it was actually because it was running, but I had changed from the default port in /etc/memcached.conf

Answer (score 6):

memcache is diffrent with memcached

and i thing you have installed memcache because `$memcache = new Memcache();` worked

you must started it on your server

check this [10 baby steps to install Memcached Server and access it with PHP](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/25/10-baby-steps-to-install-memcached-server-and-access-it-with-php/)

Comment: I know, its just they work the same. I didn't really care wich one, and memcached it was..