# Memcache: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, object, memcached

I installed memcached in a CentOS following [this steps](http://kb.liquidweb.com/install-memcached-on-centos-5/)

This is the PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/piscolab/public_html/keepyourlinks.com/includes/funciones.php on line 22
```

Code:

```
/* MEMCACHE */
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->pconnect('localhost',11211);

/* checks in memcache, if not: query and save to memcache */
function cache_query($sql,$nombre,$tiempo = -1){
    if($tiempo == -1) $tiempo = time() + 24*60*60*365;
    $consulta = $memcache->get($nombre);  /* THIS is the line */
    if ( $consulta === false) {
        $consulta = mysql_query($sql);
        $memcache->set($nombre,$consulta,0,$tiempo);
        $_SESSION['tQ']++;
    }else $_SESSION['tQC']++;
    return $consulta;
}
```

I call the function so:

```
$result = cache_query('select * from users','all_users');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$memcache` object is [out of scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) here.

Add the following line to the top of your function:

```
global $memcache;
```

Or pass it as a parameter:

```
function cache_query($sql, $nombre, $memcache, $tiempo = -1) {
    ...
}
$result = cache_query('select * from users','all_users', $memcache);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did add the global and now php doesn't log any error or print any HTML code, any idea?

Comment: This is probably because now the lines after `$memcache->get()` are being run since it doesn't throw a fatal error anymore - there must be a mistake in those lines.

Comment: Because just making an object global **can't** cause problems like that :)

Comment: Don't do that, open a new question for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
global $memcache;
```

In your function.

See this for info on variable scope:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: well if I write: global $m = new memcache(); /* or memcached */ the script fails (if i remove the line, the script works)

Comment: You shouldn't do `global $var = something;`. You use `global $varname;` inside functions to access variables that are declared outside the function, otherwise the variable is out of scope. You accepted the other answer, which says the same thing, so all is good on your original question, right?